In 2024 are there large deposits of CNY in China that earn no interest
This article implies China's household savings rate is positive and high.
Link to a news article.
A quote...

China has long had one of the highest saving rates in the world — a
reflection of the country's weak safety net.
What's different now is depressed sentiment. For years, the property
sector helped boost growth, and now it's cratering — bringing
household wealth down with it.
Zoom out: China's strong household savings are helping fund the
government's subsidies for the manufacturing sector that's drawing
pushback from global competitors, including the U.S.

So the article says some household savings are being lent to the manufacturing sector, indirectly by way of the government.  What else is happening to household savings?  Certainly households have some currency and that is earning no interest.  Are there, right now in 2024, large deposits (say of over 10 million CNY, like the size of the deposits of financial institutions and companies) of any kind in China that earn no interest?
For example, in the United States, previous to 2008, financial institution deposits held at the Federal Reserve paid no interest.
Link to an article "Why did the Federal Reserve start paying interest"
